# Automapper: validation exception ignoring destination property

Tags: c#, .net, mapping, automapper

I have troubles trying to ignore a destination property

Source class:

```
public class ClassDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Destination class:

```
public class ClassModel
{

    public int Id { get; set; }

    public IList<string> ListString { get; set; }

}
```

Example:

```
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dto = new ClassDto { Id = 1 };

        var config = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
        {
            cfg.CreateMap<ClassDto, ClassModel>().
            ForMember(i => i.ListString, opt => opt.DoNotUseDestinationValue()); 
        });

        config.AssertConfigurationIsValid();

        var mapper = config.CreateMapper();

        var model = mapper.Map<ClassDto, ClassModel>(dto);

    }
}
```

Unfortunately config.AssertConfigurationIsValid(); rises an exception:

> $exception    {"\nUnmapped members were found. Review the types and members below.\nAdd a custom mapping expression, ignore, add a custom
> resolver, or modify the source/destination type\nFor no matching
> constructor, add a no-arg ctor, add optional arguments, or map all of
> the constructor
> parameters\n===================================================\r\nClassDto
> -> ClassModel (Destination member list)\r\nAutoMapperFoo.ClassDto -> AutoMapperFoo.ClassModel (Destination member list)\r\n\r\nUnmapped
> properties:\r\nListString\r\n"}   AutoMapper.AutoMapperConfigurationException

I can't undesrtand why, I explicit to ignore ListString by DoNotUseDestinationValue

Thanks in advance

Comment: `UseDestinationValue()` does not mean ignore mapping the member. It means do not initialize it with a new object (if mapped, map onto the existing value). AutoMapper still attempts to map the member. If there was no matching source member to map, validation will throw an exception because `UseDestinationValue()` means to keep the member's existing value whether a mapping exists or not. Confusing naming choice, but that's how it works.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> By default, AutoMapper tries to map all the properties from the source
> type to the destination type when both source and destination type
> property names are the same. If you want some of the properties not to map
> with the destination type property then you need to use the AutoMapper
> Ignore Property in C#. Learn more [AutoMapper Ignore Property in C#](https://dotnettutorials.net/lesson/ignore-using-automapper-in-csharp/)
>
> Automapper gives the property **Ignore** which tells the mapper to not
> take the value of a property from the source class. **Ignore** not only
> ignore the mapping for the property, but also ignore the mapping of
> all inner properties. It means that if the property is not a primitive
> type, but another class, that if you are using Ignore, this class
> properties won't be mapped. So, A.B.C would be A.Null.

So try using this:

```
.ForMember(x => x.ListString, opt => opt.Ignore())
```

Comment: As far as I know Ignore is obsoleted, we must use DoNotUseDestinationValue

Comment: Well, my bad, I did not know about this, do you have any valid source regarding this?

Comment: well, I made a mistake. I can't reach the documentation I read and your solution work. So thanks and nevermind

Comment: No Problem! Happy to help ^_^

Comment: `Ignore()` will bypass mapping for the destination member. `UseDestinationValue()` will not replace the destination member with a newly constructed object, but will still attempt to map it. However, there is a subtle bug with `UseDestinationValue()` that will throw a validation exception that the member remains unmapped, even though it was. If you know that no source member exists, use `Ignore()`.